# How to access a member of a pointer to object

Tags: c++, pointers

I need some clarification about this issue. I have a class called con.

```
class con
{
 public:
 con();
 int readIndex;
}
```

in con.cpp:

```
con::con()
{
readIndex = 0;
}
```

in main:

```
con = new con();
```

now readIndex is not 0  as I wanted. Watch window shows that the value is `0xcdcdcdcd {???}` and the type is now `int*` and not `int` which means that a variable will become a pointer if it's class object is created using `new`? I then tried to change the code to `*readIndex = 0;` but I got a write access violation. So how should I set the value of readIndex to 0 after all?
`

Comment: `0xcdcdcdcd` = uninitialized heap memory.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892 Your code for con::con() must not be what you typed.

Comment: Post an example that demonstrates the problem instead of describing code that we can't see.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Also you may want to read a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: ***Your code for con::con() must not be what you typed.*** Or perhaps you are looking at the variable too soon (before it was initialized in the constructor) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list

Comment: @drescherjm  you are right I looked too soon. after initialization I got 0x00000000 {???}  as readIndex value but of course that's not what I need. What is the right syntax to set the value as 0?

Comment: `con::con() : readIndex  {} { // c++ statements for the constructor}`

Comment: `con = new con();` doesn't compile. Post real code.

Comment: @Pete it does compile. I forgot to add that I declared it as con* con;

Comment: I would avoid naming a variable the same as the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should definitely initialize readIndex to 0. Just put one print statement and check whether your constructor called properly or not.

Also try with

`con::con():readIndex(0)
{
}`

Comment: I tried that but still no progress. My confusion here is why readIndex is treated by visual studio as a pointer.

Comment: Are you checking the value by using break point? you are probably checking the value before it initialize. It must initialize the value with 0. No compiler should treat readIndex as a pointer. Something wrong in your debugging. Just declare con *c = new con(); before your statement and check.

Comment: Success. changing  con = new con();  to con *con = new con();  solved the problem. Many thanks Abhijit